# File permission on composer update

Tags: php, symfony

The **app/cache** and **app/logs** folder mode has been set to 0777. And apache run user and group same with cli user. Running

```
php app/console cache-clear
```

works fine as well. But the problem is when composer update, I always get:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   The directory
>   "/home/userx/symfony/app/cache/dev/annotations" is not
>   writable. Both, the webserver and the console user need access. You
>   can manage access rights for multiple users with "chmod +a". If your
>   system does not support this, check out the acl package.
>
> cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers]
>
> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"
>   command.

What could be the issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure is this the same user? `mkdir app/cache/test` and `ls -l app/cache`. you will see the difference between `test` and others.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cache warmup is responsible here. It creates file in `app/cache/dev` and `app/cache/prod` after you update composer.

You should make sure that all the folders inside `app/cache` and `app/logs` are writable, that is :

```
chmod -R 0777 app/cache app/logs
```

`777` is maybe a bit too permissive but that will do if you work locally. If you're in a production environnement, you should `chgrp` instead and give `rw` permissions to the group only, not everybody.